# Get date range of a week given a week number, month number, and year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I'm creating a stored procedure to display certain records within a date range based on week number, month number, and year number.

For example:

```
Month = 4 [APRIL]
Week  = 2 [Week 2 for APRIL]
Year  = 2017
```

The output should be: [Start day should be Sunday]

```
STARTDATE  |  END DATE
4-2-2017   |  4-8-2017
```

Searched everywhere, having a hard time already with this one.

EDIT:
I've provided a sample query for reference

```
@Month int,
@Year int,
@WeekNumber int

SELECT
(start date of the week based on week num, month, year) as DATE1,
(end date of the week based on week num, month, year) as DATE2
WHERE
StartDate = (start date of the week based on week num, month, year)
EndDate = (end date of the week based on week num, month, year)
```

Comment: This might help
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1328016.aspx

Comment: Thank you. But didn't answer my question, unfortunately. The parameters needed are week number, month number, and year only, not the full date.

Comment: can you include sample data of where you are gonna execute the query against

Comment: @CurseStacker - Please see my edit.

Comment: no, the actual data inside the table, that you need to fetch.

Comment: The actual data has nothing to do to the output of the query since i will use the date range[DATE1 and DATE2] somewhere in my where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this can help.

**Example Updated for 2008**

```
Declare @Month int = 4
Declare @Year  int = 2017
Declare @Week  int = 2


Select DateR1 = min(RetVal)
      ,DateR2 = max(RetVal)
 From (
        Select *,WkNr = Dense_Rank() over (Order by DatePart(WEEK,RetVal))
         From (Select Top (40) RetVal=DateAdd(DD,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),cast(str((@Year*10000)+(@Month*100)+1,8) as date)) From  master..spt_values) D
      ) A
 Where WkNr=@Week
```

**Returns**

```
DateR1      DateR2
2017-04-02  2017-04-08
```

Comment: "'DateFromParts' is not a recognized built-in function name." - i am using 2008 R2.

Comment: @TheNoob give me a moment

Comment: sure. a quick feedback would be much appreciated

Comment: Worked even for first and last week of months with less than 7 day count. Thank you Sir!

Comment: @TheNoob Happy it helped.     See edit where we select top 40 rather than top 31.  A little extra wiggle room just in case.

Comment: Just one more thing Sir @John Cappelletti, last week of months with incomplete number of days doesn't seem to work. Could you help me out on this? The rest are flawless.

Comment: @TheNoob  See my comment above regarding top 40.  You could make this number as high as you want